# Collection contains with @Query

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

Is there a way to use a "contains" function in a `@Query` tag? If no, what is the best way to implement this?

Example:

```
@Query("From User u  where u.roles contains :role")
List<User> findByRole(@Param("role") Role role);
```

The `User` class does have a `Collection` containing their `Roles`.

Edit: As suggested i tried it with like, the application starts, but when this method gets executed a "not matching expected type" exception occurs.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Just use the following query and you're done:

```
@Query("From User u where :role member u.roles")
```

Comment: can you link to the official doc?

Comment: What doc do you mean? Of `@Query` annotation or JPA spec?

Comment: A specs doc for the 'member' expression.

Comment: You can look [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/JPQL_BNF#Where). There is a definition of `collection_member_expression` in this section.

Answer (score -5):

Use the like keyword.

```
@Query("From User u  where u.roles like :role")
```

Comment: You want to select all roles with keyword `'role'`?

Comment: maybe this isn't clear or i guess it's not that easy to implement. I want to get all Users that have the passed in Role. Role is a seperate class an not a String and "u.roles" is a collection holding every Role of the user.

Comment: i tried List<User> findByRoles(Role role); and it seems to work fine.

Comment: If role is a collection then do something like this `from User u, Role r where r.roleName like "%administrator%" and r.roleId=u.roleId`

Comment: The question is about collection membership and not substring